# How to change frame of gradient layer at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, gradient

When I run the app the gradient layer frame doesn't match with `UIView` frame. I tried with below code:

```
let color1  =  UIColor(red: 20.0/255, green: 43.0/255, blue: 81.0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let color2  =  UIColor(red: 149.0/255, green: 45.0/255, blue: 122.0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = self.backBarcodeSrch.bounds
gradientLayer.colors =  [color1,color2 ]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.6)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.6)
self.backBarcodeSrch.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Comment: You just need to paste above code inside the viewDidLayoutSubviews() method and please make sure you're adding gradient layers once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update the `frame` of `gradientLayer` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` in your `ViewController`.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.backBarcodeSrch.bounds
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addGradient()
    }

    func addGradient() {
        let color1  =  UIColor(red: 20.0/255, green: 43.0/255, blue: 81.0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let color2  =  UIColor(red: 149.0/255, green: 45.0/255, blue: 122.0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

        gradientLayer.frame = self.backBarcodeSrch.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors =  [color1,color2 ]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.6)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.6)
        self.backBarcodeSrch.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: We do not need to use 'var' in the:
> var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
Because we do not change the link to the CAGradientLayer object
It is better to use "let"

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
func addGradientLayer() {
let color1  =  UIColor(red: 20.0/255, green: 43.0/255, blue: 81.0/255, alpha:1.0).cgColor
let color2  =  UIColor(red: 149.0/255, green: 45.0/255, blue: 122.0/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = self.backBarcodeSrch.bounds
gradientLayer.colors =  [color1,color2 ]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.6)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.6)
self.backBarcodeSrch.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
addGradientLayer()
}
```

Comment: It creates a new `CAGradientLayer` multiple times